# Fancybox will not show YouTube an Images without class-Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, youtube, fancybox

i have some Links in my CMS without an Class-Tag.
Now i will show YouTube Videos in fancybox.

But this Code will not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href^=www.youtube.com/watch], a[href$=.jpg], a[href$=.gif], a[href$=.png]').fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        helpers : {
            media : {}
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This is the link:

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aU7Os2KCRVw" target="_blank">
```

I have also test with this code, but it will not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('a[href^=http://www.youtube.com/watch]').fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        helpers : {
            media : {}
        }
    });
    $('a[href$=.jpg], a[href$=.gif], a[href$=.png]').fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        helpers : {
            media : {}
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Can someone help me please?
Greets Hendrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose your URL in quotes, otherwise slashes will be interpreted as delimiters within the expression

```
$('a[href^="http://www.youtube.com/watch"]').fancybox({
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none',
    helpers: {
        media: {}
    }
});
```

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yDb2A/)</kbd>